# Efficient way to search a string in an array of string in C. (Case insensitive)

Tags: c, string, search

I am working on a project (implemented in C) where we are required to maintain a list of a features or keywords. The user enters a string. We need to do case insensitive search for this string in the stored array of string. The list currently consists of 100 strings and new strings may be added (5 strings a year or so).

I want to know the best way to store this array and make the search more efficient.

The solution which is currently implemented is something like below:(I have not compiled this code. This is just a code snippet.)

```
    char **applist={ asdf , adgh, eftg , egty, ...} 
    char *user_input; // this string contains user entered string
    int id;
    switch(user_input[0])
    {
     case 'a':
     case 'A':
     switch(user_input[1]
     {
     case 's':
     case 'S':
     id=0
     break;

     case 'd':
     case 'D':
     id=1
     break;
     }
     break;
     case'e':
     case'E':
     switch(user_input[1])
     {
     case 'f':
     case 'F':
     id=2
     break;

     case 'g':
     case 'G':
     id=3
     break;
     }
     break;
     }
    if(stricmp(user_input,applist[id]))
    return id;
    else 
    return -1;
```

In actual code applist is not sorted. As new strings are added to applist I need an efficient way to store this array.

If I store the string sorted alphabetically then every time a new string is added I have to manually find the correct position of the new string. (New Strings are added to applist before compiling the code not at the runtime)

Suggest an efficient way of doing this.

**EDIT:** My current approach leads to a longer code but its efficient. But this code is not easy to maintain. What I need is a data structure which can do search with same efficiency as this but with smaller code. The datastructure you suggest, should not have additional overhead. The only requirement is efficient searching. And a way to add elements to the data structure at compile time easily. Sorting at run-time is not my requirement as new strings are added at compile time(This is to avoid restrict user from adding any new string to the list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One good data structure for this might be a TRIE:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

It sort of looks like this is what you've begun implementing in code.

Comment: Either that or a hash table. But the current structure is just horrible.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this is not a performance critical bit of code, in which case I would suggest using strcasestr to do the string comparisons. Store the keywords like so

```
char *applist[] = {"abc", "def", "geh"}
```

And then loop through them and compare the user input with strcasestr like so

```
if (strlen(applist[id]) == strlen(user_input) && 
            strcasestr(applist[id], user_input) != NULL)
    return id;
```

This approach is more concise and maintainable than using a complex data structure.
If indeed you are concerned with performance, first implement this approach, do some timing tests, and then you can decided whether you need a faster algorithm.

Comment: Actually this is a performance critical task. This function is called many times. Not only when user enters a query but it also reads strings from some configuration files and find if it matches any string.

Comment: +1 for the first sane answer so far. To quote Rob Pike: "Fancy algorithms are slow if n is small. And n is usually small."

Comment: @Ravichandra, did you test if it's performance critical, or are you just assuming? I wouldn't try to optimize it without profiling and seeing that it's really a problem.

Comment: My algorithm does 1 string comparison and few character comparison(depending on how unique the string is). My string array has many strings which are of equal length. Eg: 22 sttring of length 7.

Comment: in case of a user enters a string of length 7 then there will be 22 string comparisons in worst case using ur algorithm.(As there are 22 strings of size 7). Which will decrease the performance. This function is called many times. Hence it is performance critical.

Comment: I based my assumption about performance on the fact that you're dealing with "user input". Users can't actually enter data very fast, so I am guessing this function would be called several times per minute. If this is the case, it doesn't matter if it takes 1ms or 10ms to execute it.

Comment: This function is called many times. Not only when user enters a query but it also reads strings from some configuration files and find if it matches any string. If it was not performance critical i would have not asked this question here.

Comment: Reading strings from disk is very slow, so I suggest to cache that, otherwise any gains you make in optimizing this function will be irrelevant in comparison to disk access. Other then that I would suggest finding a good C implementation of TRIE, converting all keywords and user input into lower case, and use the TRIE to do fast lookups.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to searching for a string, the best data structure that you can use is a BST - Binary Search Tree - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree. The worst case search time will be only `O(log n)` compare to `O(n)` when using `arrays` or `lists`.

Here is a sample code with numbers (you may have to change it with strings and use `strcmp`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct node {
        int data;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;
} NODE;


NODE * newnode (int data) 
{
    NODE * n = NULL;
    if (n = (NODE *) malloc (sizeof (NODE))) {
        n->data = data;
        n->right = n->left = NULL;
    } else {
        printf("Error: unable to allocate memory \n");
    }

    return n;
}


NODE * insert (NODE * head, int data)
{
    NODE * n;

    if (head == NULL)
        return newnode(data);

    if (head->data == data) {
        printf("Info: attempting to add duplicate element : %d\n", data);
        return head;
    }

    if (head->data < data)
        head->right = insert(head->right, data);
    else
        head->left = insert(head->left, data);

    return head;
}    

void inorder(NODE * node)
{
        if (node == NULL) 
                return;

        inorder(node->left);
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        inorder(node->right);
        return;
}

int lookup(NODE * head, int data)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return 0;

    if (head->data == data)
        return 1;

    if (head->data < data)
        return lookup(head->right, data);
    else
        return lookup(head->left, data);
}

void search(NODE * head, int data)
{
    if (lookup(head, data)) {
        printf("found : %d \n", data);
    } else {
        printf("not found : %d \n", data);
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{
    int sum = 35;
    NODE * root = NULL;

    root = insert(root, 20); 
    root = insert(root, 10); 
    root = insert(root, 22); 
    root = insert(root, 23); 
    root = insert(root, 24); 
    root = insert(root, 25); 
    root = insert(root, 10); 
    root = insert(root, 20); 
    root = insert(root, 30); 
    root = insert(root, 40); 
    root = insert(root, 50); 
    root = insert(root, 60); 
    inorder(root);  printf("\n");

    search(root, 10);
    search(root, 11);
    search(root, 13);
    search(root, 14);

    return 0;
}
```

OTOH, hast tables will yield you constant search time O(1) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: My algorithm does 1 string comparison and few character comparison(depending on how unique the string is). But you approach will lead to more then 1 sting comparisons most of the time. String comparisons are costly.

Comment: And my requirement is sorting or adding new string before code-compilation not at run time.

Comment: @Ravichandra I just saw your new update on the requirement. As you have mentioned, the nested `switch-case` is just not easy to maintain. And more over, its not scale-able (say if the user is introducing a new keyword which is not covered in the switch-case, then you need to code it then). OTOH, you mentioned 100 existing keywords and 5 new keywords per year. So you cannot expect the developer/user to sort the keywords manually later. So my suggestion would be to handle everything in the code - sorting and searching.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, Hashtable would be ideal but the efficiency depends on the hash algorithm.

Comment: w.r.t string comparison - unless you use a hash algorithm, you need to relay on basic string compare library like `strcasecmp()`.

Comment: As i mentioned in the question user is not allowed to add a new string to the array.

Comment: Is it possible to generate a header file with sorted array whenever a developer wants to add a new string to the array?

Comment: or it could be in a text file. You program reads that text file during boot-up/initialization.